# How to make an associative array from a string in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array

Assume now I have a string:

```
$detail = "1=>Apple, 2=>Cheesecake, 3=>Banana";
```

How do I convert or parse the string `$detail` to an associative array and become like this:

```
$detail_arr['1'] = "Apple";
$detail_arr['2'] = "Cheesecake";
$detail_arr['3'] = "Banana";
```

OR

like the code below:

```
$detail_arr = array("1"=>"Apple", "2"=>"Cheesecake", "3"=>"Banana");

foreach($detail_arr as $x=> $x_name)
{
    echo "Price=" . $x . ", Name=" . $x_name;
}
```

and will display:

```
Price = 1, Name = Apple, ...
```

Comment: If the key is the price then you can only have one item in your array with the same price.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `explode()` to convert to string by `,` delimiter and loop through result

```
$arr = [];
foreach (explode(',', $detail) as $item){
    $parts = explode('=>', $item);
    $arr[trim($parts[0])] = $parts[1];
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/nncdn)

Also you can use `preg_match_all()` and `array_combine()` to do this work.

```
preg_match_all("/(\d+)=>([^,]+)/", $detail, $matches);
$arr = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```